# Xcode 6 Swift: place 2 blocks on either side of the screen?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I need to place 2 blocks on either side of the screen in the upper left and right hand corners. This seems simple and I've made several attempts, yet the blocks are no where to be seen. I've tried using both `CGPoint` and `CGPointMake` and just using number coordinates but the blocks are not appearing in the GameScene.

These blocks are going to be moving down in position later. I initialize everything here:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var savior = SKSpriteNode()

var block1Texture = SKTexture()
var block2Texture = SKTexture()
var blocksMoveRemove = SKAction()
let blockGap = 150
var block1 = SKSpriteNode()
var block2 = SKSpriteNode()
```

Here is where I need to set the position of the blocks:

```
  //Create blocks

    block1Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "block1")
    block2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "block2")
    block1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: block1Texture)
    block2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: block2Texture)

    block1.setScale(1)
    block2.setScale(1)
    block1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.2, y: self.size.height * 0.1)
    block2.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.8, y: self.size.height * 0.1)

    self.addChild(block1)
    self.addChild(block2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the blocks to your node with `addChild:`.

More remarks:

You do not have to initialize your variables when declaring them if you anyway intend to overwrite them. Instead, use force unwrapped variables.

```
var block1 : SKSpriteNode!
```

If you want the blocks in the *upper* corners, your `y` should be the height times `0.1`, not `0.9`.

Also, you might not see anything because the image is not found (check the name) or does not contain visible elements.

Also, note that the `frame` property might have an unexpected value. From the docs:

> The frame is the smallest rectangle that contains the node’s content, taking into account the node’s xScale, yScale, and zRotation properties. Not all nodes contain content of their own.

Comment: Ok. I added the blocks with `addChild` and deleted the reference to `frame` entirely. I even tried setting the position to number coordinates like (20, 20) to see if that did anything. The name on the assets are correct. When I change "block1" to another, bigger pic however it shows up barely in the lower left corner. What's going on? I edited the code in my question

Comment: Never mind. The images were just too small and too far off the screen. Thanks